# End-To-End Delay calculation in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

Dears,

To calculate the end to end delay manual, i found can do this by bellow equation

`EED = current simulation time - creation  time of packet` ..

So can any one advice me exactly what mean here ? i'm using omnet++ 4.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: plz any update .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate end-to-end delay for example this way:

```
void Txc::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
   // ...
   simtime_t eed = simTime() - msg->getCreationTime();
}
```

`simTime()` returns current simulation time.